# how to remove the arrow mark from the pagiantion in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

In codeigniter Pagination ,I have the pagination links like below.

EG 1 :  1 2 3 >  Last ›

EG 2 :   ‹ First  < 5 6 7 8 9 >  Last ›

From the above link how to remove the  ">" all arrow mark from the pagination link.

is any keyword set in config parameters.

My code :

```
  public function index()
    {        
        $limit = ($this->uri->segment(4) > 0)?$this->uri->segment(4):0;
        $config['base_url'] =base_url().'/dep/index/';
        $config["total_rows"] = sizeof($this->MODEL_NAME->COUNT_DEP($companyID, $sortBy, $orderBy));     
        $config['per_page'] =5;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4; 
        $config['next_link'] = '';
        $config['prev_link'] = '';       
        $config['num_links'] = 2;   
        $data["CE"] = $this->MODEL_NAME->get_dep($dep_id, $sortBy, $orderBy,$config["per_page"], $limit);
        $data["total_count"] = $config["total_rows"];
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);    
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links(); 
        $this->load->view('dep/home',$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with following 4 options:

```
$config['next_link'] = '';
$config['prev_link'] = '';
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
```

Answer (score 1):

I want your code, but try this

```
$config['next_link'] = '';
$config['prev_link'] = '';
```

Comment: I had added my code.Thanks for your help.Arrow removed but how to remove the arrow after Last link.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $config['next_link'] = '<img src="'.base_url().'backend/images/right-arrow.png" >';
    $config['prev_link'] = '<img src="'.base_url().'backend/images/left-arrow.png" >';
    $config['base_url'] = ''.base_url().'admin/home/userList/?id='.$id.'';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';        
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open']='<li><a href="[removed]void(0);" class="page_active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close']='</a></li>';
```